# I need some tips on how to encrypt a byte of string block by block using AES ECB

Tags: python-3.x, padding, caesar-cipher

I am trying to encrypt a plaintext using AES_ECB after its been padded so that it is a multiple of 16 by encrypting each block (16 bytes each) individually using loops but I am having trouble understanding how to do it. I am a beginner in python so I have trouble finding the right syntax.

I know I have to first separate the string into 16 bytes each and then encrypt each block by itself and then join them together to get the encrypted value I am assuming loops will be required for this. Any assistance/tips are much appreciated.

I have implemented a padding scheme that pads if necessary and then prints out the string of bytes with padding (if required) but now I'm having trouble figuring out how to encrypt it block by block with the given string of bytes (let's call it 'encoded_string').

Comment: Kindly note that Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. Secontly you should split your question in some parts like "Looping", "Encryption" and "Decryption". Just a note on security: AES in ECB mode is **unsecure** in most use cases and should be avoided, better use modes like "CBC" or "GCM".

Comment: I understand I am just trying to make some thought of how to do so I am not asking for code explicitly but maybe just an understanding of what needs to be done.